# Find x value corresponding to function peak/max in R

Tags: r, max

I want to find where a function peaks(x value) and not just what the peak value(y value) is, which can be easily done for a range of values, say p.

```
max(func(p))
```

Comment: If `p` is a vector, then this may work: `p[func(p) == max(func(p))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either one. The 2nd one works if the same max value appears for many p.

```
p[which.max(func(p))]

p[which(func(p) == max(func(p)))]
```